# ASP MVC4 and Azure - Bundling and Minification stopped working for me when I publish to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

In the Windows Azure Publish Settings I have selected:

```
Environment: Production
Build Configuration: Release
```

In my Web.Release.config I have:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
```

I had bundling working before and I made no code changes that I know of. However now
when I publish to the cloud and view web pages it seems there is no bundling at all. 
All the javascript and CSS are downloaded one by one.

Is there something I am missing?  This used to work and now it seems not to work at 
all.

Do I need to explicitly set the following:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
```

Or this:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) {
   ...
   ...
   BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

Note that when I added the above line I got a message saying: EnableOptimizations is a property but is used like a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set debug to false in web config

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
```

And it should work as expected!

Oh, one more thing:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Overrides Web.Config settings, so if this is set to true and Web.Config is set to debug it should work as well.

If you want to use that, check that you actually added BundleTable... in the right place, like this:

```
   public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

**EDIT: Including a working BundleConfig for reference**

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/wf").Include(
             "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
             "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
             "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
             "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
             "~/Scripts/jquery.wf.overrides.js",
             "~/Scripts/popup.unobtrusive.js"));
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; 
        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I am trying out all your suggestions. I will report back in a while.

Comment: Works great now with BundleTable.EnableOptimizations added. Can you tell me is that something new? I have had the same code for a long time and it seems like only now is it not doing bundling. However what I may have done recently is to click update in Nuget on the package that is used for bundling.

Comment: Great! I'm glad i could help :) Generally, i've mostly used debug="false" for the release specific web.config, but BundleTable works great as well. This official Bundling and Minification technique is new for ASP.Net 4.5.